# Print Portion of the Browser Window to PDF and Send To Server to be Faxed

Tags: javascript, c#, pdf

Like the title says, I have a requirement to print a part of the browser window to PDF and then send it to the server so that it can be faxed.  I have already found a faxing service so the real problem is in figuring out how to generate the pdf to begin with.  I have come up with several options to do this, however all of them come with significant downsides.  They are:

- Use `window.print()` on a button click along with print media queries and have the user download the resulting PDF and re-upload it to be faxed.  The problem with this is that it is a multi-step process and my users would prefer to just click a single button
- Use a library like [jspdf](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) to generate the pdf, output to a byte array and upload it to the server.  This will work, however it looks terrible because I lose all styling and my print media queries will not be applied.  So far, this is my best option
- Render the HTML server side and generate a PDF from that.  This will work fine, however it requires duplicating all of the work I have done client side (this is a SPA app) along with duplicating the maintenance.
- Use a rendering service or library to run the client side application in a headless browser and generate the PDF from that output.  This would be very complicated from a security perspective as the application lives behind a login page.

I would appreciate any suggestions not listed above as well as any advice on how to eliminate the cons posed by these options.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like using `jspdf` to render the PDF along with a library such as `html2canvas` to convert the printable region into an image to preserve styles will get the job done.  It has taken some work to configure everything properly (and I'm not through yet) but I am confident this solution will be effective.